# How to access shadowFunction of element1 form shadowRoot of other element2 in polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer-2.x

This is my html structure,

```
//--this is index.html--//
<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
</body>


//--this is my-app.html--//
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <my-page1></my-page1>
  <my-page2></my-page2>
</dom-module>


//--this is my-page1.html--//
<dom-module id="my-page1">
  <script>
    class MyPage1 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-page1'; }

      covert_data(){
        alert("in covert_data");
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyPage1.is, MyPage1);
  </script>
</dom-module>


//--this is my-page2.html--//
<dom-module id="my-page2">
  <paper-button on-tap="addData">Save</paper-button>
  <script>
    class MyPage1 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-page2'; }

      addData(){
        var host = document.querySelector('my-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('my-page1');
        host.covert_data();
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyPage2.is, MyPage2);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

`<my-page1></my-page1>` has 1 method called `covert_data()`. I am trying below code.

**way1:**

```
  var host = document.querySelector('my-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('my-page1');
  host.covert_data();
```

This giving me error `host.covert_data is not a function`

**way2:**

```
  document.querySelector('my-page1').covert_data();
```

This giving me error `Cannot read property 'covert_data' of null`

> How to call that `covert_data()` method in `<my-page2></my-page2>` in
>   polymer 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting with the solution i would like to give you a tip.

> Please make sure that you post a working piece of code.

It's been quite a few months since i worked `Polymer` and it took me 15-20 minutes just to get your code working. An in that 15-20 minutes i thought about leaving it lot of times.

Posting a working code will help people on community to help you better.

**Now to solution**

I found lot of issues in your code. I don't know which were because of writing incomplete code in `SO` and which genuine, so i'll point them all.

- `script` tag and registration missing for `my-app`.
- `constructor` and `Super` missing for all the elements.
- `template` tag is missing for `shadowDom`.

I don't know why your `way 1` is not working, it's working fine for me. I can only guess it might be because of missing `constructor`, but `way 2` will not work and `my-page1` is not present directly in `document`. It's part of `shadowRoot` of `my-app`.

Below is the working snippet of your code. I've changed `on-tap` to `on-click` to avoid importing `gesture` events files.

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">


<!-- my-app element -->
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>   
    <my-page1></my-page1>
    <my-page2></my-page2> 
  </template>
  <script>
    class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'my-app'
      }
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyApp.is, MyApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>


<!-- page1 element -->
<dom-module id="my-page1">
  <script>
    class MyPage1 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'my-page1';
      }
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
      covert_data() {
        alert("in covert_data");
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyPage1.is, MyPage1);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<!-- page2 element -->
<dom-module id="my-page2">
  <template> <div on-click="addData">Save</div></template>
  <script>
    class MyPage2 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'my-page2';
      }
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
      addData() {
        var host = document.querySelector('my-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('my-page1');
        host.covert_data();
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyPage2.is, MyPage2);
  </script>
</dom-module>



<!-- calling element -->
<my-app></my-app>
```

Comment: first, thanks for this meaningful answer......my `way 1` is not working for me because, whenever i refresh `my-page2`  the instant of `my-page1` might be destroy.....and that `convert_data()` will getting undefined.....***then how to handle this situation***....if you are using `iron-pages` with routing then you can replicate this issue....!

Comment: I am uising `on-tap` instead of `on-click` because `on-click` produce 200ms delay while user interaction.....and it will cause unnecessary delay in animation.

Comment: @TusharAcharekar Is `convert_data` a generic function? If so, then extract it in a `behavior` and then you can use it in both the pages. But, if it depends on some specific user input from `page1` then on refresh you might have to load page 1 again as that data might be lost on refresh

Comment: @TusharAcharekar using `on-tap` is not an issue. I used `on-click` just for the snippet so as not to import `gesture` events. Actually, as far as i remember `Polymer` promotes using `on-tap`. If you notice carefully i did not mention `on-tap` is the list of issues found as it is not one.

Comment: yes, `on-tap` is not problem, i aware about  that, but i just share my experience.

Answer (score 1):

In `page1.html` :

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('upway-func', {detail: {op:"Optionally I can send some data"}}));
```

In `myApp.html` define id to child element in order to call a function and on-upway-func event :

```
  <my-app>
    <page1 on-upway-func="callPage2Func"></page1>
    <page2 id="child2"></page2>
</my-app>
...
callPage2Func(op){
    console.log(op)//Optionally I can send some data
    this.$.child2.covert_data(op);
}
```

Comment: Your answer may be right, but i want to access `<my-page1>` shadow method in `<my-page2>` showroot,  .......Please check my updated question....!